# File format to store curves in 3d

Tags: 3d, vector-graphics, data-interchange

SVG is a standard format for storing a flat curve, that is (x, y) coordinates. Is there a format that can be used to interchange (x, y, z) values, or is the standard option csv or json in this case, that is no standard.